# Grails and plugin-provided views

Tags: grails-plugin

I was wondering if there has been any development on the bug http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-2685 ? It says that it's resolved but when I try to use it in 1.3.1 (latest at the time of writing as far as I know) it still does not work.

Comment: Lots of plugins provide views - could you share some details about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sure.
I have a plugin that contains one domain class (News), one controller (NewsController) with one action (index) that returns a map with just one parameter (message: "Hello") and the view itself translates the message to <h1>${message}</h1>. That's the whole plugin.
Now what I do in my app is to use <g:include controller="news" action="index"/>. If I put the view into grails-app/views/news folder in my plugin the g:include fails to render the content but when I move the view to the same location but in the application everything works just fine.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my plugin is linked to the application in BuildConfig.groovy using   grails.plugin.location.'portal-news' = "../portal-news"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great news! With the emergence of Grails 1.3.3 the views provided by plugins in a way described here works again! So the actual solution is to upgrade to 1.3.3 and life is good :D